# Class to use for a situation?

Tags: android

Hi Android developers,

I need a class for a part of my program. Let me describe the problem for you.

I need to have a class that lets me **scroll** down a list of "items" that I can **click**. Also, this list of items can grow **(expand) or shrink as needed**, like an ArrayList.

I saw the class ScrollView, but does this fulfill all of the requirements I need?

If not, what is the best class to use in my main.xml file to accomplish this task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `ListView` in your XML file and then populate the listview from an `Arraylist`. Something like this will work for you.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity 
{
private ListView lv;
public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
     lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);
     // Instanciating an array list (you don't need to do this, you already have yours)
     ArrayList<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
     your_array_list.add("a");
     your_array_list.add("b");
     // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a first // parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your array as a third parameter
     ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
     new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, your_array_list);
     lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
     setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

}
}
```